# Why doesn't C compile log with variables but does compile with magic numbers?

Tags: c

We found that C will compile the log function when used with magic numbers, but not with a variable.  Any ideas?

Comment: You're looking for the word "literal constant". "magic number" is not an acceptable synonym for "literal constant".

Comment: I meant magic numbers as in hard coded numbers. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/constants/ Shows that literal constants mean a base ten number assigned to a variable.  Do I understand that right?  Could you give an explanation?  Thanks

Comment: In the most general sense, spanning all kinds of programming languages, literals are all data items of any type which are part of the body of the program itself (rather than run-time input): character literals, string literals, numeric literals or even complex data structure literals.  Constants are expressions in the program which have an unchanging value. Constants can be symbolic (defined symbols) or they can be literals. Literals don't have to be constant, but when they are not, it gives rise to self-modifying code: to change a literal is to change the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you didn't link your program to the math library and with a literal your compiler is probably using a builtin function.

With `gcc` you will get the same error with `-fno-builtin` with a literal.

Link with lib math this way: `gcc bla.c -o bla -lm`

Answer (score 0):

We found that it is because of the version of the C compiler.  Newer versions seem to support log better.